# How to include git dependencies in setup.py for pip installation

Tags: python, git, pip, setup.py

I need to include Python packages available via public Github repositories along with my Python (2.7) package. My package should be installable via `pip` using `setup.py`.

So far, this could be done using `dependency_links` in the `setup.py` file:

```py
setuptools.setup(
   name="my_package",
   version="1.0",
   install_requires=[
       "other_package==1.2"
   ],
   dependency_links=[
      "https://github.com/user/other_package/tarball/master#egg=other_package-1.2"
   ]    
)
```

This still works when the package gets installed with the `--process-dependency-links` flag, but the `dependency_links` functionality seems to be deprecated, since:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/my_package@master#egg=my_package-1.0 --process-dependency-links
```

gives me the following warning:

```
DEPRECATION: Dependency Links processing has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
```

Is there an alternative way to include `git` dependencies in the `setup.py` file with support for pip installation?

Edit (10/17/2016) to clarify my use case:

Let's say I find a bug in `other_package`. I fork the respective repo on Github, fix the bug and make a pull request. My pull request doesn't get immediately accepted (or never will be because the package is no longer actively maintained). I would like to distribute `my_package` together with my fork of `other_package` and want users to be able to pip install `my_package` without any further knowledge about the details of this requirement and without having to provide any additional flags upon installation. Users of `my_package` should further be able to include `my_package` as a requirement in their own custom packages.

How can this be achieved bearing compatibly with different modes of installation (wheels, eggs, develop, ...) in mind?

Comment: Also in a managed environment, you cannot always specify `--process-dependency-links` like in a standard Google App Engine but external private repositories are needed for requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this exact issue (found a bug in someone else's project that mine depended on, made a pull request but didn't have time to wait for them to merge).

I solved it by adding this line to `install_requires`:

```
'my-package @ https://github.com/user/my-package/archive/master.tar.gz'
```

Comment: As a note, I've since found out that PyPI won't allow you to publish a package that has a URL as a dependency. If you need to publish on PyPI the other answer from Philip is better.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would avoid including git repositories as dependencies. In the scenarios you describe, I see two options.

**Where Package is Unmaintained**

If a package is unmaintained, you can either fork the project and distribute your own version, or you can distribute the forked code as as a submodule of your own code (i.e. include the external dependency directly in your distributable package)

Personally I prefer distributing my own version.

**Where the package has yet to include your bugfix**

In this case, I would distribute the fixed code as a part of your package until such a time as the bug is fixed.

Comment: @h345k34cr I appreciate why this answer may seem frustrating. Unfortunately since the deprecation of the feature I'm not aware that it can be done and I'm under the impression that the reason it was deprecated was because it should not be done. As such, I provided options as a way for people to achieve the same ultimate ends given that the feature no longer works and that the removal of said feature is by design, rather than offering a kludgy workaround which breaks things.